# Finding the tangent line of curve $x^2y^2+5xy=14$ at $(2,1)$

Tags: tangent-line

I want to check if my work is correct.

> Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve at (2, 1)$$^2^2 + 5 = 14(1) $$
> solution:
>
> > The tangent is a straight line so it will be of the form:
> > $y=ax+b(2)$
> >
> > > Where $a$ is the slope of the equation of the tangent to the curve $(1)$ at point $(2,1)$, and line $y=ax+b$ passes through
> > > $(2,1)$.
> > > So that, we can get a by finding the $1st$ $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ derivative as this is the gradient of the line.
> > > Applying Implicit Differentiation for $(1)$:
> > > \begin{alignat*}{1}
> > > 2xy^2+x^2y\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+5y+5\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=0
> > > \end{alignat*}
> > > So, at $(2,1)$ it reduces to:
> > > \begin{alignat*}{1}
> > > &\ 9+9\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=0\\
> > > \Leftrightarrow &\ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-1\\
> > > \Leftrightarrow &\ a=-1
> > > \end{alignat*}
> > > $(2)$ become:
> > > $y=-x+b$.
> > > $(2)$ passes through $(2,1)$:
> > > \begin{alignat*}{1}
> > >     &\ 1=-2+b\\
> > >     \Leftrightarrow &\ b=3
> > > \end{alignat*}
> > > Thus, the line $y=-x+3$ is a equation of the tangent line to the curve $x^2y^2+5xy=14$ at
> > > $(2,1)$
> > > Sol2:
> > > \begin{align}
> > > ^2^2 + 5 = 14
> > > \end{align}

Comment: your implicit derivative is not correct

Comment: @Lion Heart oh right, i was see it. Thank you

Comment: $(x-2)^2 (y-1)^2 + 2 (x-2)^2 (y-1) + (x-2)^2 + 4 (x-2) (y-1)^2 + 13 (x-2) (y-1) + 4 (y-1)^2 + 9 (x-2) + 18 (y-1)=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2xy^2 + 2x^2yy' + 5y + 5xy'=0$$
$$y'=-\frac{2xy^2+5y}{2x^2y+5x}$$
$$m=y'(2;1)=-\frac{1}{2}$$
and the equation of tangent line at the point $(2;1)$ is $y=-\frac{1}{2}x+2$